# (Android) Can not insert data into SQLite database

Tags: java, android

I tried a lot of fixes but still can not find out why the data can not be inserted.I used a tool called BD Browser for SQLite to check the data and there are tables and columns but no values..

Codes:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private Button btnadd,btnselect;
private EditText etmiles,etdate,etcosts,etprice;

SQLiteDatabase db;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btnadd=(Button)findViewById(R.id.add);
    btnselect=(Button)findViewById(R.id.select);
    etmiles=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.miles);
    etdate=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.date);
    etprice=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.price);
    etcosts=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.costs);
    db=SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(this.getFilesDir().toString() + "/my.db3", null);



    btnselect.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Activity02.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
     btnadd.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {


        String amiles=etmiles.getText().toString();
        String sdate=etdate.getText().toString();
        String sprice=etprice.getText().toString();
        String acosts=etcosts.getText().toString();
        if(etmiles.getText().toString().length() == 0||etdate.getText().toString().length() == 0||etprice.getText().toString().length() == 0||etcosts.getText().toString().length() == 0)
        {
            Toast toast=Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "xxxx", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
            return;
        }
        else
        {

            try{
                db.execSQL("insert into test1('" + sdate + "','" + amiles +  "','" + sprice + "','" + acosts +  "')");

                }
                catch(SQLiteException e)
                {
                    db.execSQL("create table if not exists test1(sdate varchar(40) primary key,amiles varchar(30),sprice varchar(30),acosts varchar(30))");
                }        
        Toast toast=Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "xxxx", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
        }
        }
    });

}
```

}

Error message:near")":syntax error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your `INSERT` statement doesn't match SQLite's syntax. Try adding `VALUES` like so:

```
INSERT INTO test1 VALUES (..., ..., ...)
```

And in truth on Android you should consider the [insert()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues)) method instead.

Answer (score 1):

you should use [insert(String table, String nullColumnHack, ContentValues values)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues))

where table is the name of the table you want to insert, `nullColumnHack` it is optional and can be null, and values is a map which contains the value we want to insert. The key of this map is the column name. E.g.

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues(); 
values.put(HISTORY_ORDER_ID_COL, orderId); 
values.put(HISTORY_PRODUCT_ID_COL, productId); 

long rowId = db.insert(TABLE_ORDER, null, values);
```

android will take care of writing the insert query for you.